# Connect tables using Inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have 3 tables and 2 forms.

```
TABLE 1:  table1ID | studentnumber | remarks

TABLE 2: table2ID | others
```

`OUTPUT` would be like this

```
table3: ID | studentnumber
```

How can I connect those 2 forms using Inner Join? The student number will connects them.

my code:

```
$sql = SELECT studentnumber
       FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.table2ID = studentnumber.tableID;
```

Comment: pls more info. You have 3 tables but you show 2. And what forms? I dont understand whats your problem is

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question.  Is table2ID linked/foreign-keyed to studentnumber?

Comment: You haven't defined `table3ID`.

Comment: The Id mentioned in the table3 is table1id or table2id? what is the common column to join table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.StudentNumber, t1.remarks, t2.StudentNumber 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

However, given the output needed there is no need to do a join as the information is held all in Table1.